# How to detect a variable in a function from a variaible outside it?

Tags: python

Here is an example

```
new = '1'
def test():
    n = 'Hello world'
    new = n
print(new)
test()
```

The result:

```
>>>1
```

I wanted the 'new' variable in the function will change the value of the 'new' variable outside so the new can replace number 1 and change it to the string: 'Hello world'

Comment: A variable that is assigned within a function is a *local variable* by default, completely unrelated to any variable with the same name elsewhere.  You can override this by explicitly declaring the variable as `global` within the function.

Comment: You should use `global` tag inside your function to override `new`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `global` keyword. (That being said, in general, I wouldn't suggest using `global` unless you have a strong reason for doing so.)

```py
new = '1'
def test():
    global new
    n = 'Hello world'
    new = n
test()
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have suggested using `global` variables, but global variables can introduce bugs that can be difficult to trace.

Better to pass any data into your function as an argument, and have the function return the result.

In your simple example there is no argument to be passed, so we just need to return the required value:

```
new = '1'
def test():
    return 'Hello world'
    
new = test()
print(new)
```